# Can i override jquery.load function?

Tags: jquery, load

Unfortunately i haven't realized that the callback parameter for jquery.load function will run regardless of the request result, successful or not. So i have used the load function in quite a lot of places. Now i need to prevent the callback function, which should only run in case of a success result, from running in case of a failed response. How can I override the default jquery.load function to check the result first, before delegating to the default jquery.load function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code will check whether your load function is success or not.You can configure the flow based on the textStatus

```
$("body").load("/Main_Page",function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
if (textStatus == "success") {
        console.log("DONE");
     // all good!
}
if (textStatus == "error") {
     // oh noes!
    console.warn("ERROR");
}
});
```

Comment: I know how to fix this one by one. The reason i wanted to override the default .load function is just to save time as i've got too many places using this pattern.